# Please help me override this GoogleTrustedStore block!

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks

I'm having trouble overriding this block for a customization on admin orders:
`Mage_GoogleTrustedStore_Block_Adminhtml_OrderCreatedConfirmation`

`app\code\core\Mage\GoogleTrustedStore\Block\Adminhtml\OrderCreatedConfirmation.php`

```
class Mage_GoogleTrustedStore_Block_Adminhtml_OrderCreatedConfirmation
extends Mage_GoogleTrustedStore_Block_OrderConfirmation_Onepage
{}
```

```
    <global>        
       <blocks>
          <kmd_googletrustedstore>
             <class>Kmd_Googletrustedstore_Block</class>
          </kmd_googletrustedstore>
          <googletrustedstore>
             <rewrite>                
                <orderConfirmation_Onepage>Kmd_Googletrustedstore_Block_Onepage</orderConfirmation_Onepage>
             </rewrite>
             <rewrite>
                <adminhtml_OrderCreatedConfirmation>Kmd_Googletrustedstore_Block_Adminhtml_OrderCreatedConfirmation</adminhtml_OrderCreatedConfirmation>
             </rewrite>
          </googletrustedstore>
       </blocks>
    </global>
```

My custom file is located here:
`app\code\local\Kmd\Googletrustedstore\Block\Adminhtml\OrderCreatedConfirmation.php`

```
class Kmd_Googletrustedstore_Block_Adminhtml_OrderCreatedConfirmation
extends Kmd_Googletrustedstore_Block_Onepage
{  
}
```

The `orderConfirmation_Onepage` rewrite works fine for frontend orders, but I can't get the adminhtml block rewrite to work - any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Update - I checked for conflicting overrides, none found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be working:

```
class Kmd_Googletrustedstore_Block_Adminhtml_OrderCreatedConfirmation
  extends Mage_GoogleTrustedStore_Block_Adminhtml_OrderCreatedConfirmation
{  
}
```

You're rewriting `Mage_GoogleTrustedStore_Block_Adminhtml_OrderCreatedConfirmation` according to your `config.xml` hence you have to extend this class.

Comment: yup that does make sense, thanks for the tip - unfortunately still not hitting that class. Let me try adjusting the casing...

Comment: try `<adminhtml_orderCreatedConfirmation>Kmd_Googletrustedstore_Block_Adminhtml_orderCreatedConfirmation</adminhtml_OrderCreatedConfirmation>` (lower case `o` in `orderCreatedConfirmation`) .. strange but working for me in that case